# inserting data from one table to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table say `TblA` with columns like

```
+---------------+
| Field         | 
+---------------+
| a             | 
| b             |
| c             |
| d             | 
| e             | 
| f             | 
+---------------+
```

I want to insert this data into `TblB` like

```
+---------------+
| Field         | 
+---------------+
| id  (Autoincrement) | 
| a             | 
| b             |
| c             |
+---------------+
```

and `TblC` like

```
+---------------+
| Field         | 
+---------------+
| id  (Equal to the one in tblB) | 
| d             | 
| e             |
| f             |
+---------------+
```

Is there some way in mysql to do this? Or the only way to do this is write a script?

Comment: Does tblA have its own primary key?

Comment: yes a is the primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is primary key for `tblA`, then you can do this in two steps:

```
INSERT INTO tblB (a,b,c)
SELECT a,b,c FROM tblA
```

followed by:

```
INSERT INTO tblC (id,d,e,f)
SELECT b.id,a.d,a.e,a.f
FROM tblA a
JOIN tblB b ON a.a = b.a
```

Comment: one more thing i forgot to mention how to acheive this when the field a is a text field and is the only field which can be unique

Comment: if that field (tblA.a) is really unique, it will work no matter what type it is - integer or string

Comment: yea i understand that but matching say 500 chars in a sql query is going to take forever when u have 2 million entries in the db. any suggestions about how to index would be totally helpful

Comment: you can create synthetic primary key (like autoincrement) - that should help a lot

Comment: +1 I didn't know that we can use select join for the source of insert. :D

Comment: What's more is that in some SQL engines this is a primary usage and `VALUES(a,b,c)` typically used in `INSERT` is actually internal synonym for `SELECT a,b,c`. For example, in PostgreSQL you can use `VALUES(a,b,c)` as statement of its own, not as part of INSERT. [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9eecb/2)

Answer (score 0):

Though @mvp helped me to comeup with this approach when you dont have any primary key in `tblA` I thought I would post it here.

First add a new autoincrement column called id using

```
  ALTER TABLE TblA 
  ADD COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, 
  ADD primary KEY id(id);
```

then do

```
INSERT INTO TblB (id, a, b, c) 
SELECT id, a, b, c FROM TblA;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO TblC (id, d, e, f) 
SELECT id, d, e, f FROM TblA;
```

Comment: And this is one more example why it is always good to have short primary keys from the very beginning :-)